# SwiftUI - @Binding:String from DatePickerView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uidatepicker

I am trying to get a @Binding:String value returned from a DatePickerView in SwiftUI.

Can anyone tell me where the formatting code should go?.. I have so far tried in .onAppear which generates an initial value but doesn't update (NS)... also tried in the body and .onDisappear .. but nothing gets returned ...

```
struct DateView: View {

        @Binding var dateString: String
        @State var selectedDate: Date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        var body: some View {

            formatter.dateFormat = "d MMM y"
            dateString = formatter.string(from: selectedDate)
            print(self.dateString)

            return DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("Select a date")
            }.labelsHidden()
        }
    }
```

tried

```
struct DateView: View {

        @Binding var dateString: String
        @State var selectedDate: Date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        var body: some View {

            DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("Select a date")
            }.labelsHidden()
                .onAppear(){

                    self.formatter.dateFormat = "d MMM y"
                    self.dateString = self.formatter.string(from: self.selectedDate)
                    print(self.dateString)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Asperi retried your solution and it worked perfectly .. repost so I can acknowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @ObservedObject var value = SelectionChnage()
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   var body: some View {
    DatePicker(selection: $value.selection, displayedComponents: .date) {
           Text("Select a date")
        }.labelsHidden()
   }
```

}

```
final class SelectionChnage: ObservableObject {
var selection: Date = Date() {
    didSet {
        date_formate(slectedate: selection)
    }
}
```

}

```
func date_formate(slectedate: Date) {
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "d MMM y"
let dateString = formatter.string(from: slectedate)
print(dateString)
```

}